# Open the file with admin privilege in ruby

Tags: ruby, hosts

On windows machine(with Windows 7 running, x86-64) is it possible to open 'etc/hosts' file which is in system32/drivers/etc, modify it and save from ruby?

I get "not opened for writing(IOError)" error
The code is very simple

`file = File.open("C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts")
file << "new line"`

Comment: Is it because of the windows protected files? Maybe you  have to turn this off for the hosts file.

Comment: You have to open your file in write mode. Sorry I didn't see this at first :)

Comment: If you want to append something to the file, open it with 'a+' mode, please read File.open documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to acquire privileges from code ( which maybe won't be portable across different windows OS'es ), do like this:

- open a command prompt as an administrator
- run your script from there

By doing like this, all the programs you're executing will have administrative privileges as well.

EDIT: This is your problem:

```
file = File.open("C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts","w")
file << "new line"
```

You have to open the file in write mode.

Comment: yeap, I have tried it, but it still says "not opened for writing (IO Error)"

Answer (score 0):

My best work around is have ruby open an elevated command prompt when necessary.  It will prompt the user for a password, but it is better than nothing.

```
username = `whoami`.chomp
run = "runas /noprofile /user:#{username} \"cmd /C #{cmd}\""
system(run)
```

`cmd` can be any command that you want to run with permissions. What I do to edit a host file is:

```
hosts_path = 'C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'
hosts_file = File.open(host_path,'r') {|f| f.read}
...
    --edit the hosts_file here--
...
cmd = "echo \"#{hosts_file}\" > #{hosts_path}"
```